# How to incorporate indexed images into a web page

Tags: html, css

I want to use [indexed images](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/indexed-images.html) in my web page. However, they are read as text/html so they just won't show:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
body {
   background: #FFFFFF;
   background-image: url("imagenes/conversacion/backgroundConversacion.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: 50% 6.2%;
   overflow: hidden;

   user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -o-user-select: none;
}
```

Edit: No, the url is not wrong. Also, here is the type of the other .png (non indexed images) i've used.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure your paths are correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm completely sure

Comment: "However, they are read as text/html " — The URLs do return HTML … but they also have a 404 status meaning "Not Found". You just got the URL wrong (either because its just plain wrong or you failed to upload it).

Comment: "Edit: No, the url is not wrong. " — The server says 404 Not Found, so either the URL is wrong or you have some exceptionaly esoteric server-side logic performing tests on images and 404ing if it doesn't like a feature of them.

Comment: Actually, that's exactly whats happening. I'm using the robot Pepper to display the web and aparently its internal server doesn't like anything that is not a "regular" .png. Guess I'll have to find another way to compress the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) said, this might be either a mistake on the path (which is not) or some server-side problem that is messing up the image. Since i'm using the robot Pepper to display it, I guess that the only option left is that internally it's messing up my image, so it's not a problem with the code (as I thought) but a problem with the robot.